# cassandra date not working while retrieving already inserted data

Tags: date, cassandra, timestamp

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS part_prices_by_context_run_at ( "
            + "context text, run_at timestamp,feed_type text, "
            + "part text, price double, "
            + "PRIMARY KEY ((context, run_at), part))"    

"INSERT INTO part_prices_by_context_run_at  (context,run_at,feed_type,part,price)" +
```

" VALUES ('US|en-us|consumer','2014-12-10 01:00:00','partial','MXFL1/A',236.29)"

```
String oldstring = "2014-12-10 01:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
date = format.parse(oldstring);

PartPricesByContextRunAtKeyImpl key = new PartPricesByContextRunAtKeyImpl();
key.setContext("US|en-us|consumer");
key.setRunAt(date);

Collection<PartPricesByContextRunAt> partPrices = dao.retrievePartPrices(key);
Assert.assertNotNull(partPrices);
```

Assert fails as partPrices is always null and throws below error

**Error: unable to coerce 'Wed Dec 10 01:00:00 PST 2014' to a  formatted date (long)**

Looks like while querying, the date becomes 'Wed Dec 10 01:00:00 PST 2014' but what was inserted is different format i.e '2014-12-10 01:00:00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `run_at` is a **timestamp** datatype I guess you should set the value of `run_at` as Long and compare times in millis.

```
key.setRunAt(date.getTime());
```

After retrieving also, you can compare the time millis.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row

row.getDate("run_at").getTime()
```